# ul>li>checkbox>href

Tags: jquery

How do I get the values ​​marked with links, attribute href="" and text links. I apologize for my english. Thank you.

```
<ul id="list-item">
<li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><a href="http://localhost/">Item 1</a></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" /><a href="http://localhost/">Item 2</a></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" /><a href="http://localhost/">Item 3</a></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" /><a href="http://localhost/">Item 4</a></li>
<input type="button" id="save" value="Save"/>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the output/result you want to get.

Comment: @voffka: See my answer below, hope you want something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are trying to achieve this:

**Edit:**

```
$('#list-item input[checked=checked]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).next('a').text() + ': ' + $(this).next('a').attr('href') )
})
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eGFwR/)

Comment: I think it is so. i am going to check

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#list-item input[type="checkbox"]:checked').next('a').attr('href');
```

You can use the `change` event for mapping the texts and links of the anchors, try the following:

```
var anchors = [];
$('#list-item input').change(function(){
   var anchors = $(this).closest('ul').find('input:checked').siblings('a').map(function(){
                    return $(this).text() + ": " +this.href
               }).get()    
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HKmh7/2/)

Comment: I need the links marked with checkboxes, but not all. should not be checking? input:checked?

Comment: I think the OP means those links next to a selected checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `find` method to get the value of elements under an element. then use jquery `each` method get value in the collection:

Something like this.

```
function getAnchorValues(){
    var checklist = $('#list-item').find($('input[type="checked"]:checked');
    $.each(checklist, function(index, val){
        alert index + ' : ' +  val;
    });
}
```